# MySQL Federated Engine Cartridge on Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

By default Federated Cartridge on Openshift is disabled.
After the recent update from Openshift I was unable anymore to update the my.cnf file (permission denied)

Is there any successful way to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are able to change some of the settings of mysql through environment variable (https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html)you won't be able to make changes like that to your my.cnf file within the gear. You could however try making a custom mysql gear that has federated engine enabled.

Comment: Thanks, after doing more researches I was able to build a custom gear that has federated engine enabled as per your suggestion.